# Count of matches in two fields of different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables with products that contain information about the invoice number, product code, manufacturer, brand, model and article. The Brand and Article fields may contain null values.

For example

```
Table1
+-------------+--------+-----------+-------+---------+---------+
| Num         | Code   | Developer | Brand |Model    | Article |
+-------------+--------+-----------+-------+---------+---------+
| 111/111/111 | 0803   | Dev1      | Bra1  | Mod1    | Art1    |
| 222/222/222 | 0706   | Dev2      | Bra2  | Mod2    | Art2    |
| 222/222/222 | 0706   | Dev2      | Bra2  | Mod2    | Art3    |
| 222/222/222 | 0706   | Dev2      | Bra2  | Mod3    | Art5    |
| 333/333/333 | 0717   | Dev3      | Bra3  | Mod4    | Art4    |
| 333/333/333 | 0717   | Dev3      | Bra3  | Mod4    | Art6    |
| 444/444/444 | 0805   | Dev1      | Bra1  | Mod1    | Art1    |
| 444/444/444 | 0805   | Dev1      | Bra1  | Mod1    | Art7    |
+-------------+--------+-----------+-------+---------+---------+

Table2
+-------------+--------+-----------+-------+---------+---------+
| Num         | Code   | Developer | Brand |Model    | Article |
+-------------+--------+-----------+-------+---------+---------+
| 666/666/666 | 0803   | Dev1      | Bra1  | Mod1    | Art1    |
| 777/777/777 | 0706   | Dev2      | Bra2  | Mod7    | Art7    |
| 777/777/777 | 0706   | Dev2      | Bra2  | Mod7    | Art7    |
| 888/888/888 | 0717   | Dev3      | Bra2  | Mod4    | Art4    |
| 888/888/888 | 0717   | Dev3      | Bra3  | Mod4    | Art4    |
| 888/888/888 | 0717   | Dev3      | Bra3  | Mod8    | Art8    |
| 999/999/999 | 0805   | Dev1      | Bra1  | Mod1    | Art1    |
| 999/999/999 | 0805   | Dev1      | Bra1  | Mod1    | Art7    |
+-------------+--------+-----------+-------+---------+---------+
```

I joining tables by  fields Code and Developer and use listagg (or other) function to aggregate fields Brand, Model  and Article. As a result, I get the following table

```
+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+------------+
| Num_Tab1    | Num_Tab2    | Developer | Model_Tab1 | Model_Tab2 | Art_Tab1       | Art_Tab2   |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+------------+
| 111/111/111 | 666/666/666 | Dev1      | Mod1       | Mod1       | Art1           | Art1       |
| 222/222/222 | 777/777/777 | Dev2      | Mod2;Mod3  | Mod7       | Art2;Art3,Art5 | Art7       |
| 333/333/333 | 888/888/888 | Dev3      | Mod4       | Mod4;Mod8  | Art4;Art6      | Art4;Art8  |
| 444/444/444 | 999/999/999 | Dev1      | Mod1       | Mod1       | Art1;Art7      | Art1;Art7  |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+------------+
```

Additionally, I need to find the count of matching unique values of brands, models and articles for each pair of invoices.

```
+-------------+-------------+------+------------+------------+----------------+------------+-------+-----+
| Num_Tab1    | Num_Tab2    | Dev  | Model_Tab1 | Model_Tab2 | Art_Tab1       | Art_Tab2   | Mod_c |Art_c|
+-------------+-------------+------+------------+------------+----------------+------------+-------+-----+
| 111/111/111 | 666/666/666 | Dev1 | Mod1       | Mod1       | Art1           | Art1       | 1     | 1   |
| 222/222/222 | 777/777/777 | Dev2 | Mod2;Mod3  | Mod7       | Art2;Art3,Art5 | Art7       | 0     | 0   |
| 333/333/333 | 888/888/888 | Dev3 | Mod4       | Mod4;Mod8  | Art4;Art6      | Art4;Art8  | 1     | 1   |
| 444/444/444 | 999/999/999 | Dev1 | Mod1       | Mod1       | Art1;Art7      | Art1;Art7  | 1     | 2   | 
+-------------+-------------+------+------------+------------+----------------+------------+-------+-----+
```

But I can't do that.

I tried using the regexp_count() function, using a field from one table as the row and a field from the second table as the pattern, replacing "; " with "|". It works, but some of the invoices contain a large number of items, so I get error regular expression too long ora-12733.
I also tried adding a column to the query

```
SELECT ... , (SELECT count(*)
              FROM Tab1 t1 JOIN Tab2 t2 ON t1.Model=t2.Model )
FROM Tab1 t1 JOIN Tab2 t2 ON t1.Code=t2.Code AND t1.Developer=t2.Developer
WHERE ...
```

but get error.
I tried to include a similar subquery in the "FROM" section, but unfortunately, this did not produce the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query where tables are joined by CODE and DEVELOPER (the one using LISTAGG()) could have two additional count columns that you ask for. Use conditional (t1.MODEL = t2.MODEL / t1.ARTICLE = t2.ARTICLE) distinct Count() analytic function like below. You will get duplicate rows which you should get ridd of either using Distinct keyword or Group By

```sql
WITH    --    S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl_1 (NUM, CODE, DEVELOPER, BRAND, MODEL, ARTICLE) AS
        ( Select '111/111/111', '0803', 'Dev1', 'Bra1', 'Mod1', 'Art1' From Dual Union All
          Select '222/222/222', '0706', 'Dev2', 'Bra2', 'Mod2', 'Art2' From Dual Union All
          Select '222/222/222', '0706', 'Dev2', 'Bra2', 'Mod2', 'Art3' From Dual Union All
          Select '222/222/222', '0706', 'Dev2', 'Bra2', 'Mod3', 'Art5' From Dual Union All
          Select '333/333/333', '0717', 'Dev3', 'Bra3', 'Mod4', 'Art4' From Dual Union All
          Select '333/333/333', '0717', 'Dev3', 'Bra3', 'Mod4', 'Art6' From Dual Union All
          Select '444/444/444', '0805', 'Dev1', 'Bra1', 'Mod1', 'Art1' From Dual Union All
          Select '444/444/444', '0805', 'Dev1', 'Bra1', 'Mod1', 'Art7' From Dual
        ), 
    tbl_2 (NUM, CODE, DEVELOPER, BRAND, MODEL, ARTICLE) AS
        ( Select '666/666/666', '0803', 'Dev1', 'Bra1', 'Mod1', 'Art1' From Dual Union All
          Select '777/777/777', '0706', 'Dev2', 'Bra2', 'Mod7', 'Art7' From Dual Union All
          Select '777/777/777', '0706', 'Dev2', 'Bra2', 'Mod7', 'Art7' From Dual Union All
          Select '888/888/888', '0717', 'Dev3', 'Bra2', 'Mod4', 'Art4' From Dual Union All
          Select '888/888/888', '0717', 'Dev3', 'Bra3', 'Mod4', 'Art4' From Dual Union All
          Select '888/888/888', '0717', 'Dev3', 'Bra3', 'Mod8', 'Art8' From Dual Union All
          Select '999/999/999', '0805', 'Dev1', 'Bra1', 'Mod1', 'Art1' From Dual Union All
          Select '999/999/999', '0805', 'Dev1', 'Bra1', 'Mod1', 'Art7' From Dual
        )
```

```sql
--    S Q L :
Select Distinct
            t1.NUM "NUM_TABLE_1", t2.NUM "NUM_TABLE_2", t1.CODE, t1.DEVELOPER,
            LISTAGG(Distinct t1.MODEL, ';') WITHIN GROUP (Order By t1.MODEL) Over(Partition By t1.NUM, t2.NUM, t1.CODE, t1.DEVELOPER) "MODEL_TABLE_1", 
            LISTAGG(Distinct t2.MODEL, ';') WITHIN GROUP (Order By t2.MODEL) Over(Partition By t1.NUM, t2.NUM, t1.CODE, t1.DEVELOPER) "MODEL_TABLE_2", 
            --
            LISTAGG(Distinct t1.ARTICLE, ';') WITHIN GROUP (Order By t1.ARTICLE) Over(Partition By t1.NUM, t2.NUM, t1.CODE, t1.DEVELOPER) "ARTICLE_TABLE_1", 
            LISTAGG(Distinct t2.ARTICLE, ';') WITHIN GROUP (Order By t2.ARTICLE) Over(Partition By t1.NUM, t2.NUM, t1.CODE, t1.DEVELOPER) "ARTICLE_TABLE_2",
            --
            Count(Distinct Case When t1.MODEL = t2.MODEL Then t1.MODEL End) Over(Partition By t1.NUM, t2.NUM, t1.CODE, t1.DEVELOPER) "MOD_C", 
            Count(Distinct Case When t1.ARTICLE = t2.ARTICLE Then t1.ARTICLE End) Over(Partition By t1.NUM, t2.NUM, t1.CODE, t1.DEVELOPER) "ART_C" 
From        tbl_1 t1
Inner Join  tbl_2 t2 ON(t2.CODE = t1.CODE And t2.DEVELOPER = t1.DEVELOPER)
Order By    t1.NUM, t2.NUM
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
NUM_TABLE_1  NUM_TABLE_2  CODE  DEVELOPER  MODEL_TABLE_1  MODEL_TABLE_2  ARTICLE_TABLE_1  ARTICLE_TABLE_2  MOD_C  ART_C
-----------  -----------  ----  ---------  -------------  -------------  ---------------  ---------------  -----  -----
111/111/111  666/666/666    0803    Dev1   Mod1           Mod1           Art1             Art1                 1      1
222/222/222  777/777/777    0706    Dev2   Mod2;Mod3      Mod7           Art2;Art3;Art5   Art7                 0      0
333/333/333  888/888/888    0717    Dev3   Mod4           Mod4;Mod8      Art4;Art6        Art4;Art8            1      1
444/444/444  999/999/999    0805    Dev1   Mod1           Mod1           Art1;Art7        Art1;Art7            1      2
*/
```

**NOTE**:
If there are situations that there are no rows in Table2 for any CODE and DEVELOPER in Table1 and you need those rows too then use Left Join and handle null values from Table2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` to concatenate the two tables and then use conditional aggregation to merge the rows:

```sql
SELECT MAX(CASE tbl WHEN 1 THEN num END) AS num_tab1,
       MAX(CASE tbl WHEN 2 THEN num END) AS num_tab2,
       code,
       developer,
       LISTAGG(DISTINCT CASE tbl WHEN 1 THEN model END, ';')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY tbl, model) AS model_tab1,
       LISTAGG(DISTINCT CASE tbl WHEN 2 THEN model END, ';')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY tbl, model) AS model_tab2,
       LISTAGG(DISTINCT CASE tbl WHEN 1 THEN article END, ';')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY tbl, model) AS article_tab1,
       LISTAGG(DISTINCT CASE tbl WHEN 2 THEN article END, ';')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY tbl, model) AS article_tab2,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE model_tab_count WHEN 2 THEN model END) AS mod_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE article_tab_count WHEN 2 THEN article END) AS art_count
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(DISTINCT tbl) OVER (PARTITION BY code, developer, model)
           AS model_tab_count,
         COUNT(DISTINCT tbl) OVER (PARTITION BY code, developer, article)
           AS article_tab_count
  FROM   (
    SELECT 1 AS tbl, t.*
    FROM   table1 t
  UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS tbl, t.*
    FROM   table2 t
  ) t
)
GROUP BY code, developer
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Num, Code, Developer, Brand, Model, Article) AS
SELECT '111/111/111', '0803', 'Dev1', 'Bra1', 'Mod1', 'Art1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '222/222/222', '0706', 'Dev2', 'Bra2', 'Mod2', 'Art2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '222/222/222', '0706', 'Dev2', 'Bra2', 'Mod2', 'Art3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '222/222/222', '0706', 'Dev2', 'Bra2', 'Mod3', 'Art5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '333/333/333', '0717', 'Dev3', 'Bra3', 'Mod4', 'Art4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '333/333/333', '0717', 'Dev3', 'Bra3', 'Mod4', 'Art6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '444/444/444', '0805', 'Dev1', 'Bra1', 'Mod1', 'Art1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '444/444/444', '0805', 'Dev1', 'Bra1', 'Mod1', 'Art7' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 (Num, Code, Developer, Brand, Model, Article) AS
SELECT '666/666/666', '0803', 'Dev1', 'Bra1', 'Mod1', 'Art1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '777/777/777', '0706', 'Dev2', 'Bra2', 'Mod7', 'Art7' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '777/777/777', '0706', 'Dev2', 'Bra2', 'Mod7', 'Art7' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '888/888/888', '0717', 'Dev3', 'Bra2', 'Mod4', 'Art4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '888/888/888', '0717', 'Dev3', 'Bra3', 'Mod4', 'Art4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '888/888/888', '0717', 'Dev3', 'Bra3', 'Mod8', 'Art8' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '999/999/999', '0805', 'Dev1', 'Bra1', 'Mod1', 'Art1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '999/999/999', '0805', 'Dev1', 'Bra1', 'Mod1', 'Art7' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| NUM_TAB1 | NUM_TAB2 | CODE | DEVELOPER | MODEL_TAB1 | MODEL_TAB2 | ARTICLE_TAB1 | ARTICLE_TAB2 | MOD_COUNT | ART_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 222/222/222 | 777/777/777 | 0706 | Dev2 | Mod2;Mod3 | Mod7 | Art2;Art3;Art5 | Art7 | 0 | 0 |
| 333/333/333 | 888/888/888 | 0717 | Dev3 | Mod4 | Mod4;Mod8 | Art4;Art6 | Art4;Art8 | 1 | 1 |
| 111/111/111 | 666/666/666 | 0803 | Dev1 | Mod1 | Mod1 | Art1 | Art1 | 1 | 1 |
| 444/444/444 | 999/999/999 | 0805 | Dev1 | Mod1 | Mod1 | Art1;Art7 | Art1;Art7 | 1 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qCMBZ31f)